# Is there a proper way to implement a subclass with a different method signature than its super class in Python?

Tags: python, interface, signature, super, subclassing

I've defined a super class as a formal interface that other developers will write subclasses to implement, however the arguments to the method will vary by implementation:

```
class FormalInterface:
  """ Subclasses will have varying arguments for formal_method """
  def formal_method(*args, required_arg=0):
    raise NotImplemented('Implement me')

  def get_arguments():
    """ Tells the user what arguments need to be passed """
    raise NotImplemented('Implement me')


class MyImplementationOf(FormalInterface):
  def formal_method(concrete_arg1, conrete_arg2, required_arg=0)
    # impelementation...

  def get_arguments():
    return 'concrete_arg1', 'concrete_arg2', 'required_arg'
```

This is legal python code, however warnings abound about redefining the function signature.

Am I right to just ignore the warnings in this case? Or is there a more Pythonic approach that I should be thinking about?

Comment: What warnings are you seeing?  The above runs without warnings for me.

Comment: The warnings come from code inspection tools like PyCharm and PyLint, when I override those warnings I like be sure I can justify the override, and I wasn't confident I could in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is advice on how to handle this situation in the [super-considered-super blog post](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

One way to just is to use only keyword arguments, stripping-off the ones you need and using `**kwargs` to delegate the remaining arguments to the other methods:

```
class A:
    def m(self, *, x, y):
        print(f'{type(self)=}   {x=}   {y=}')

class B(A):
    def m(self, *, z, **kwargs):
        super().m(**kwargs)
        print(f'{type(self)=}   {z=}')
```

Call the methods like this:

```
>>> A().m(x=10, y=20)
type(self)=<class '__main__.A'>   x=10   y=20
>>> B().m(x=10, y=20, z=30)
type(self)=<class '__main__.B'>   x=10   y=20
type(self)=<class '__main__.B'>   z=30
```